# EMI Filter For Low Power SMPS

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, buck, emc, emi-filtering

I've designed a 1.25W buck converter which is fed by 220VAC(85-265) and has a 5V output. Now I'm trying to design a EMI input filter for it. I don't have a PE connection so I didn't use a CM filter so I only go for DM filter.

My switching frequency is kinda low(30kHz) because of IC I use and build a filter like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEL3ir.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

filter has 3.5kHz cutoff(I calculated required cutoff according to my input ripple)

I know 1uF cap is pretty big but if I decrease it I need to increase the inductor value to keep my cutoff same you know.

problem here is; this filter need to stand between the grid and the rectifier. Since my filter cap is 1uF and we have 50Hz frequency in grid, because of the impedence of capacitor, the cap will draw much more current than SMPS(since the SMPS is 1.25W).

Question is:

Can I put the filter after the rectifier instead of putting before it?
Or
Is there any other way to design a proper filter for such a low power SMPS

Comment: See if [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/522058/95619) doesn't help.

Comment: That's a nice post, thanks but post includes dc-dc stage, I'm concerned about AC. If the SMPS is fed by AC, the EMI filter is always between AC source and the rectifier and I just wonder can I put the filter after the rectifier? What's going to change?