# Can LC filter at the input of the switching regulator cause problem?

Tags: voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, filter, switching-regulator

The system I designed uses switching power supply [Microchip MCP16311](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP16311-Family-Data-Sheet-DS20005255C.pdf) for operation.

The problem is that during Run test, which i let the board communicate with other system via Modbus, the communication seems to fail for some time while I am gone.

While there can be many possible reasons, especially including the software, I suspect that the switching power supply may be malfunction intermittently.

[image]

Above is the switching supply circuit.

Can LC filter at the input of the switching regulator cause problem?
CD2~5 are 10uF capacitors.

Comment: What is the min/max range supplied to Vin? What's the zener voltage of Z1? And what is the maximum (peak) load current drawn from the 18V output?

Comment: @MarkU 24VDC is supplied to Vin , Z1 zener voltage = 33V, Maximum load current is about 100mA.

Comment: Yes, the \$LC\$ filter can have impact on the circuit performance. A 100-µH inductor is high and exhibits a large dc resistance causing a drop when you load the converter. This inductor is usually more in the range of 1-10 µH with a larger filtering capacitor. Second, you have to know that the *incremental* input resistance of a switching regulator is negative and may badly interact with the output impedance of the filter. See my post [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/522058/stability-of-input-filter-in-smps-theoretical-explanation/522069#522069) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You suspect the power supply, but it is guilty?

Set the micro to log what it's doing via UART and record it with a PC. Let it run for a while and check the logs. You may find something like the micro rebooting just after it did something. That will narrow it down.

Next, stick a scope probe on the micro's VCC, and one on the input voltage. Set the trigger to something abnormal, like a voltage dip on VCC, or a spike/dip on VIN. Leave it for a while to record waveforms. Did it find anything?

You can set the scope to trigger on reboot or error (flip a GPIO when that happens and trigger on it). If the other board on the modbus gets communication errors you can also program it to trigger the scope when it receives erroneous data. Digital scopes will store what happened before the trigger, so if you put the trigger point on the right of the screen, you can time travel to what happened before. Then probe various things, like the modbus wires or the power supplies, and see if there is anything suspicious right before the error.

If you suspect the inductor, the simplest way to know is to put a load on the output and switch it, for example with your micro and a FET, and examine the input of the regulator. If you see ringing you don't like, grab two high value capacitors like 1000µF 35V and solder one on each side of the inductor. They should have enough ESR to form a well damped circuit with the inductor, so make sure the damping factor

\$ \zeta ={\frac {R}{2}}{\sqrt {\frac {C}{L}}} \$

is >1 with both R=cap ESR, C=cap value, L=inductor. Depending on how much capacitance there is in the power supply, the input cap may be irrelevant, so the values of R and C may vary between ESR and 2*ESR, and C ... C/2. But you get the idea. This works best with caps that have low enough ESR to be effective, but not low enough to create an undamped ringing with the ceramics.

Comment: Your suggestions for debugging software seems great. I will try those methods and let you know the results.

Answer (score 0):

I've never had problems with LC filters in front of DC/DC converters even with power hungry loads.

Time ago I designed 3 boards. Each board had DC/DC converter (*) and a GSM module which drew pulsed currents of 2 A and pulse width of 577 micro seconds.
I had an LC filter just like you in front of the DC/DC converter. L was 151 micro Henry and C was 220 micro Farad.

They are still running on the field after 15 years of work.

(*) Texas Instruments' LM2575, LM2576, LM2596

Modern DC/DC converters switch at high frequencies and unless that chip has a silicon bug, I don't think that the problem is the LC filter.

---

Add a battery powered circuit made of:

```
1 SR flip-flop
1 Schmitt Trigger inverter
1 Led
```

Design the circuit in a way that, when the 18 VDC disappears, the led is turned off.

Answer (score 0):

> *Can LC filter at the input of the switching regulator cause problem?*

Yes they can (more below) but I'm unsure whether it is the root cause of your real problem associated with your communication failure so, I'd keep looking for that.

The problem with an LC at the front input side of any regulating circuit is that if the load on the output of the regulator is moderate to high and then drops away back to a low current, you'll get input inductor flyback that may exceed the input voltage rating of the regulator.

This has happened once to me during a short circuit test of a switching regulator; once I removed the output short (a real test), the current rapidly fell to zero but the input inductor (as they naturally do) wanted to maintain the high current and responded with a spike of significant over-voltage that destroyed the regulator.

I'm not saying your regulator gets destroyed (because clearly it doesn't) but, that flyback situation may cause some problem and a knock-on effect that might disrupt communications.

So, when using a series inductor on the input to a regulator ask your self whether it is really needed. If it is then, strongly consider putting a resistor parallel to that inductor to limit the flyback voltage. There are formulas that can be used to determine that resistor value of course.

Basically what you end up, in essence, is an input RC filter but with no problems at passing DC (due to the inductor).

Maybe you should temporarily short out that inductor and see if there are still comms problems.