# Design of a Buck Converter with LC Input Filter

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, buck, homework

I am attempting to design a circuit from an exercise:

[image: Exercise]

I am stuck at point (c). I attempted to calculate the voltage and current ripple in the LC filter using the small-ripple approximation, but this yields constant inductor current. This is what I attempted to do:

[image: Attempt]

This exercise is proposed in a section of a book that is supposed to be introductory, so probably no advanced techniques are required to solve it, but I wasn't able to find a solution so far.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: If you assume L1 is infinite, what is the capacitor C1 ripple current?

Comment: "*you may assume that all inductance and capacitance values are sufficiently large*" -- here is your hint. Also, Vc=Vg (ideally), there is no switching Vg, only the current is pulsed. If the LC values would have been finite, then the peak would have been that of the lowest harmonic, attenuated by the filter.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen So, assuming L and C are very large values I can assume that in the calculation of the voltage ripple their current and voltage are constant respectively. I found some results assuming this: 1) Assuming that the current I1 is constant I calculated the voltage ripple of the capacitor using the charge-voltage relation 2) I used that voltage ripple to calculate the current ripple on the inductor
I am trying to simulate this circuit on SPICE but the converter goes straight to DCM. How can I fix this?

Comment: If the inductor is large the current ripple converges to zero, thus Vc=Vg (constant current => zero derivative). But the drawn current is pulsed and it has to come from somewhere, which means now the cap will have full current ripple (with zero average). Not lastly, be [very careful](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/522069/95619) with input filters in SMPS.