# How to design a filter for multiple buck converters

Tags: power-supply, buck, converter, passive-filter

I am designing an electronic circuit with multiple buck converters on it. All bucks are supplied by a 12V DC input voltage from a converter which is on an other card. I want that my converters don't add to much noise on the 12V input.

My question is which criteria can help me to design this filter ? I mean i have already input capacitors on my converters but i think it will be better to add inductance (LC filter) or ferrite bead.

[image]

Comment: *I want that my converters don't add to much noise on the 12V input.* Before anyone can design a filter, there needs to be a **requirement**. 1) How much **noise/ripple** can you tolerate at each load. "As little as possible" is not an answer. 10 mVpp at 100 kHz could be an answer. 2) Can the DCDC converters be designed such that this requirement can be met? yes => no filter needed no => a filter is needed. 3) How much ripple/noise is at the output of the DCDC and how much does it need to be supressed, that gives the specification for the filter(s).

Comment: Sure, what I mention above looks complicated, but suppose you design this for a customer and your customer says: "I don't want to pay for those filter components." Then what **proof** do you have to prove that you really need those filters?

Comment: Oh, my comment assumed you wanted to place filters **after** the DCDC converters (to suppress the ripple at the DCDC's outputs). You have only a filter **before** the DCDC converters. **Why**? That makes little sense as the 12 V input will be DC (or will it?).

Comment: How much noise will be too much? Numerical answer please and one that covers the important band of frequencies that the generated noise could cause problems. Also, what would be the component or PCB or system that would be vulnerable to that noise?

Comment: Hello, Yes sorry i have not drawn the output filter but i have designed them for my bucks. The input is 12V DC from the output of another card. And all my converters, which are DC/DC , take this 12V DC as input voltage. The situation is that : All my converters has been designed separately from each other. So now i'm trying to create simulations to observe how much the input voltage is pertubated by all my converters connected to the 12V.

Comment: Adding a front-end EMI filter to a single converter is already not a trivial exercise (see my answer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/522058/stability-of-input-filter-in-smps-theoretical-explanation)) so having so many cascaded dc-dc sharing a common EMI filter output will certainly complicate things. More information in my [APEC 2017](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202017.pdf) seminar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Verbal Kint ! I will check it.